# Adding and displaying a validator immediately from the codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a webpage that has several validators and a validation summary on the page. These are setup when the page is loaded because they are just things like normal expressions and required fields.

I have some other cases where when a user fills in a text box, the system must on saving check that it is valid. I would like to then show an additional message in the summary along with the originally created validators to show that the entry is invalid.

I have tried the following, but on saving nothing is shown. This method is called at the beginning of the save button click and is supposed to add a message to the validation summary and return isvalid = false.

```
protected bool ValidProductCode()
{
    bool lValid = false;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProductCode.Text))
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_ProductCodes_FillScreen", conn);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", ddlSiteId.SelectedValue);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtProductCode.Text);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOntext", 1);

                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

                da.Fill(ds);

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    lValid = true;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
        }
    }
    CustomValidator err = new CustomValidator();
        err.IsValid = false;
        err.ErrorMessage = "The product code entered is invalid";
        Page.Validators.Add(err);
    return lValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [a `CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Code-behind:

```
protected void ValidateProductCode(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value))
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_ProductCodes_FillScreen", conn))
            {
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", ddlSiteId.SelectedValue);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtProductCode.Text);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOntext", 1);

                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                args.IsValid = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validProductCode" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtProductCode"
    OnServerValidate="ValidateProductCode"
    ErrorMessage="The product code entered is invalid"
    Display="Dynamic"
/>
```

Comment: I tried this example and it didn't work. It did hit the validate code in the code-behind but never shown the error message on save.

Comment: It looks like it needs something to say what happens when args is not valid.

Comment: @connersz: Did your stored procedure raise an error? I've updated the code to set `IsValid` to `false` in the `catch` block.

Comment: @connersz: The only other change is that this code will consider an empty product code as valid; you would typically add a `RequiredFieldValidator` to the control in addition to the `CustomValidator` to handle this.

Comment: @connersz: Also, bear in mind that the validation is running on the server. The page will post back, then the validation will run. `Page.IsValid` will return `false`, and when the page is rendered back to the browser, the "invalid product code" error will be displayed.

Comment: I did try to use it with an invalid product code, the procedure returned that it was invalid and the eventargs was set to isinvalid = true but the message was never shown following postback.

Comment: @connersz: There isn't an `IsInvalid` property on the eventargs. If it set `IsValid = true`, then you wouldn't get a validation error.

Comment: OK well I'm just saying that the above code does nothing when it returns false.

Comment: I have looked further into this and found that there are two problems. The first one is that it validates and then runs the save anyway so I think I need something in the save to check things are valid before doing so and the second issue is that I can't get the message to show in the validation summary with the other messages even by using the same validation group.

Comment: @connersz: As with any other validator control, you need to check that `Page.IsValid` returns `true` *before* saving the data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa479013.aspx

Comment: That has fixed the save issue but still can't get the validation text inside the existing summary.

Comment: @connersz: Then you must be doing something odd that you've not mentioned. Make sure the `ValidationGroup` is set correctly (or not set at all) on all of the validator controls, the button, and the `ValidationSummary`. Make sure the button doesn't have `CausesValidation="False"`. Make sure the `ErrorMessage` is set correctly on the `CustomValidator`. Make sure you're not hiding the `ValidationSummary` if `Page.IsValid` returns `false`.

Comment: I've tried it all, with and without a validation group. The only thing I don't understand is your comment on hiding the validation summary. At the moment I can see the validators in the page code but on saving, the page is set to page.isvalid =false and no error is shown for anything. If I allow the custom validator to show a message on the screen outside of the summary it works.

Comment: @connersz: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that you've set `Display="None"` on the custom validator? Or have you removed the `ErrorMessage="..."` attribute?

Comment: On the validator the display is set to none which is the required property setting for the summary.

Comment: I have all the other validators working ok using the same settings until I add this one.

Comment: @connersz: Then you must be doing something strange that you haven't mentioned. I've used custom validators for years, and I've never had a problem with the error message appearing in the validation summary. Can you upload the full code of your page and code-behind somewhere?